# Aizawa attractor tending towards zero/no movement

Tags: c#, strange-attractor

Hello I am trying to visualize an Aizawa attractor and it's seems to work at first but then just stabilizes at zero/stops moving. I have looked at several implementations online and mine seems to be the same but I don't know why it stops moving.

Here's the code which takes in a point and returns the new point:

```
public class Aizawa
{
    private const float a = 0.95f;
    private const float b = 0.7f;
    private const float c = 0.6f;
    private const float d = 3.5f;
    private const float e = 0.25f;
    private const float f = 0.1f;

    public static void Iterate(float x, float y, float z, out float dX, out float dY, out float dZ)
    {
        dX = ((z - b) * x  - d * y);
        dY = (d * x + (z - b) * y);
        dZ = (c + a * z - ((z * z * z) / 3f) - (x * x + y * y) * (1f + e * z) + f * z * x * x * x);
    }
}
```

After this I just set the point as follows:

```
_xPos += dX * time;
_yPos += dY * time;
_zPos += dZ * time;
```

I'm using unity to visualize it and here is the result so far:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JopJB.png)

I have no idea where to go from here! Any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Comment: It may be better to do the calculation using double instead of float (which has rather low accuracy). Does this make a difference?

Comment: I tried that too but it's the same :(